# SAP Column IDs to an Array

Tags: vba, sap-gui

I am trying to get the column IDs of an SAP Grid. I can get the Name of a column from a selected cell with.

```
    session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell").CurrentCellColumn
```

This returns "AUFNR" which is the Id I am looking for for the selected column.
How do I cycle through the rest of the columns and put the Ids into an array to use for data extraction

Full code for the above.

```
Sub Get_Column_ID()
Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
Set SAPapp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
Set SAPCon = SAPapp.Children(0)
Set session = SAPCon.Children(0)
MyGrid = "wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell"

Range("A1").Value = session.findByID(MyGrid).CurrentCellColumn



End Sub
```

Comment: Could you give 3 samples of Column IDs that you can list from your code?

Comment: https://blogs.sap.com/2020/08/19/tip-sap-gui-scripting-vba-code-snippet-to-detect-all-ids-of-the-ui-elements/ or https://www.smartspate.com/how-you-can-automate-work-in-sap-with-vbscript/

Comment: Thank you for the Responses the code link on the left I tired and couldn't get it to work, the one on the right my work won't let me to the site. The Code below works for what I was looking for thank you all for the quick responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following :

```
Sub Get_Column_ID() 
 Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
 Set SAPapp = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
 Set SAPCon = SAPapp.Children(0)
 Set session = SAPCon.Children(0)
 set myGrid = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlGRID1/shellcont/shell")

 allRows = myGrid.RowCount - 1
 allCols = myGrid.ColumnCount - 1

 Dim columns As Object
 Set columns = myGrid.ColumnOrder

 For i = 0 To allCols
  myGrid.setCurrentCell 0, columns(i)
  ActiveSheet.Cells(1, i + 1).Value = myGrid.CurrentCellColumn
 Next

 For j = 0 To allRows
  For i = 0 To allCols
   ActiveSheet.Cells(j + 2, i + 1).Value = myGrid.GetCellValue(j, columns(i))
  Next
 Next

End Sub
```

Regards, ScriptMan

Comment: Thank you while I just needed the Column names I had the second part for pulling the Data but had to use F1 help to get the Column names and had to write new code for every Grid that was needed this will work for all!